# The argument type 'BoxConstraints' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help in my code, why I am getting this error, I updated the pub and other things but still this issue is coming. Previously this code was running without any issue.

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ));
```

ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(
^
lib/presentation/pages/widgets/product_details.dart:16:21: Error: The argument type 'BoxConstraints' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

- 'BoxConstraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart').
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(
  ^
  lib/presentation/pages/widgets/shirtBox.dart:18:21: Error: The argument type 'BoxConstraints' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.
- 'BoxConstraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart').
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(
  ^

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the spec

```
static Future<void> init(
  BuildContext context, {
  Size designSize = defaultSize,
  bool splitScreenMode = false,
  bool minTextAdapt = false,
  bool scaleByHeight = false
})
```

you're gonna have to provide your BuildContext first.

You might want to use  `ScreenUtilInit` instead as shown on the flutter_screenutil readme:

```
return ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(360, 690),
  minTextAdapt: true,
  builder: (context , child) {
```

and use `Size` instead of `BoxConstraints`

Comment: What's the error you get if you use `ScreenUtil.init(context)`?

Comment: Above I have mention the error

Comment: You have to use your BuildContext `context` instead of the `BoxConstraints` you're using. If you do that, it's impossible to get the same error you got earlier.